# Implement balanced factor with only 1 extra bit per node

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

In the book *Introduction To Algorithms - A Creative Approach*, Question 4.18:

> The AVL algorithms that were presented in Section 4.3.4 require balanced factors with three possible values: 1, 0, or -1. To represent three values we need 2 bits. Suggest a method for implementing these algorithms (with only a slight modification) with only 1 extra bit per node.

I have implemented AVL tree by recording each node's height instead of a balanced factor.

But I have no idea how to represent three values (1, 0, -1) with only 1 bit. I guess there must be some other information that can be employed to represent 1,0,-1, together with the 1 bit.

Could anyone help on this question?

Comment: don't stick your brain to -1, 0 and 1. free your creativity.

Comment: You can go for <= + > or < + >= :)

Comment: If using >= and < , how can I decide whether the tree is balanced when in below situation: R's balanced factor is ">=", after inserting a node A to the left sub tree of R, is R balanced or not?

Comment: And, no, you can't represent three distinct values with only one bit.

Answer (score 1):

If node don't have got two sons -you can calculate it
else you can remember it in sons: one bit in left son and one in right son.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Subtract the heights, `int balance = left->height - right->height`, and then use `balance <= -1`, `balance == 0` and `balance >= 1`. No need for additional bits, besides the height.</s>

Keep in each node a single bit with the meaning "this subtree is of a lower height than its sibling". There is a 1:1 correspondence between the balance factor at a node and the extra bits in its children.

```
left: 0, right: 0 <-> balance: 0
left: 0, right: 1 <-> balance: 1
left: 1, right: 0 <-> balance: -1
left: 1, right: 1 <-> invalid
```

Comment: I have implemented AVL tree by recording each node's height instead of a balanced factor.  But "height" occupies at least 8 bits.

Comment: That took _some_ time to correct. The balance influences a nodes _behaviour_ when heights change: with instance morphing, this can be kept by in each node's class.